# NHibernate Where Contains / OrderBy / Skip / Take / Select To New Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nhibernate

I'm trying to get this query to work with no luck.  I have a person object with a first name, last name, id and other fields that should not being returned.  The query should return only people where their FULL NAME contains some string value.  The query is being used for pagination as well so I have to skip records and take records.

```
Session.QueryOver<Person>()
  // Only fetch records where full name matches some string (Not working)
  .WhereRestrictionOn(person => person.firstname + " " + person.lastname)
  .IsInsensitiveLike("%bob%")
  // Order by last then first name (Works if removing non-working parts)
  .OrderBy(person => person.lastname)
  .Asc
  .ThenBy(person => person.firstname)
  .Asc
  // Select to different object (Not working)
  .Select(person => new PersonDTO()
  {
    ID = person.ID,
    Name = person.firstname + " " + person.lastname
  })
  // Skip and take (Works if removing non-working parts)
  .Skip(50)
  .Take(50)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: @stuartd The where/like isn't working and the select isn't working.

Comment: @GrantWinney System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'person' of type 'Person' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var comboItem = new ComboBoxItem();

var result = Session.QueryOver<Person>()
  .WhereRestrictionOn(person => Projections.Concat(person.firstname, " ", person.lastname))
  .IsInsensitiveLike("%bob%")
  .OrderBy(person => person.lastname)
  .Asc
  .ThenBy(person => person.firstname)
  .Asc
  .SelectList(list => list
    .Select(person => person.ID).WithAlias(() => comboItem.id)
    .Select(person => Projections.Concat(person.firstname, " ", person.lastname)).WithAlias(() => comboItem.text)
  )
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ComboBoxItem>())
  .Skip(50)
  .Take(50)
  .List<ComboBoxItem>()
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I suggest use: `IsInsensitiveLike("bob", MatchMode.Anywhere)` for more readable code.